# Is the use of "be VERB-ing" acceptable in order to suggest a continuous action after "so as to", "in order to" etc.?

Tags: continuous-aspect

Example sentences are as follows:

1. "In order for it to **be happening** it is necessary that the circumstances be right."
2. "So that it may **be happening** it is necessary that the circumstances be right."
3. "The sky has been too clear for it to **be raining** now."

Comment: "For it to be happen*ing*" sounds like InE (Indian English). In most other places, "for it to happen" is more idiomatic - perhaps because it is the *event* in its entirety that is in question, not the (part-way) progression of the event (unless, of course, it is specifically the progression that is being considered).

Comment: I generally use such form when I want to convey the obvious reason for why something hasn't happened. In your examples, it is not raining because the sky is clear and it is not happening because the circumstances are not right.

Comment: There are plenty of circumstances in which I might say *to be (verb)ing*, as an alternative to *to (verb)*, usually for emphasis.

Comment: What's wrong with the simpler form "In order for it *to happen* ..."?

Answer (score 1):

So as to/ in order to — are prepositional phrases and "be _ ing" are "continuous infinitives” in bare forms without 'to'.

Continuous Infinitives are one of the four variations of infinitives. Like other forms of infinitives, they too are tenseless but can set aspectual temporal relationship with main/ preceding verb to express an action in progress. They can be used in both active and passive forms(to be being played/ to be playing). Cf.

You may be joking(∅ to).

The second example of ... it may be happening... is an instance of ' bare continuous infinitive '.

All the examples are grammatically correct but it could have been better if simple infinitives were used in the first and last examples:

- If it is to happen...
- ... to rain now.

Answer (score 0):

I think that "In order for it to be raining,  there have to be rain clouds in the sky"   is correct.   "So that it may be raining it is necessary for there to be rain clouds"  sounds incorrect.  Even if it is "technically "  correct English,  it is not the way most people would express themselves.    The first phrase of "so that it may be raining"  is the problem.

Comment: I would say "In order for it *to rain*, ..."

Comment: I think that Trevor is right that this is certainly the more common way of saying it as well as a less convoluted. construction than "In order for it to be raining.

Answer (score 0):

I've always been a strong proponent of brevity and clarity. There is no reason to use convoluted constructions if simpler ones are available, especially if you can avoid confusing readers (and yourself) by doing so. Whether the sentences you've listed are "acceptable" is more a matter of opinion. I would not consider them acceptable because they are unnecessarily verbose. Aside from that, the third sentence simply does not make sense. If the sky *has been too clear* for it to rain, what's the use of mentioning "be raining now"? The likely intention is to suggest that it won't rain in the next few hours or near future.

The following are my suggested alternatives:

1. The circumstances must be right for it to happen.
2. The sky has been too clear for it to rain.

Answer (score -1):

I think this only works if you add the qualifier "at that time". As in "In order for it to be happening at that time, the right circumstances would have been necessary"

Comment: as stated with your other answers, please try to give a source for your answer. This site strives to provide objective answers. Find out about good answers in the [Help Center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: To maintain the proper sense of time, it would have to be "in order for it to *have been* happening at that time".